# Javascript event loop: Where do web api's get executed?

Tags: javascript, event-loop

In reading about the JS event loop, I was curious where web api's get executed. For example, in this [image](http://blog.carbonfive.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/event-loop.png), the pink box doesn't have a name (just says "implementation specific"), leaving me to wonder *where* these web api's get executed.  The call stack, event loop, message queue all have names. I've also seen Philip Roberts [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) about the event loop and he just refers to it as a "Web API".

So when a web api is reached in the call stack, it goes off and gets executed while the rest of the call stack gets run. But where does that web api call go to be executed? For example, if there's a set time out of 5 seconds, where is it sitting for those 5 seconds?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Web API", but it's exactly that: some native code doing what it is supposed to do. In the example of the linked image, it's the browsers's DOM rendering engine. In case of a setTimeout call, it's just a queue of timeouts sitting around somewhere in memory and being managed by native code in an implementation-specific manner.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, say the next item in the call stack to be called is `setTimeout` with 5 seconds. The call stack isn't going to wait for 5 seconds and then continue with the rest of the stack. `setTimeOut` goes off and gets executed somewhere else, while the rest of the call stack continues on. But *where* and *how* `setTimeout` gets executed is unclear to me from what I've tried to research.

Comment: Actually, it does not go off and is executed somewhere else, it just puts the callback in a timer queue and then returns. But yes, it could continue in a background thread and wait there for five seconds, or it could be implemented in any other manner. It does not matter. That's the job of the engine/browser. All what matters is that after five seconds the callback is placed in the message queue to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this was the question from 2 years ago, as there is no answer yet, I will try to answer this question based on my understanding. This is currently how I understand javascript, it may be not accurate everywhere since I just started to code half a year. If there is a mistake, please point out.

The simple answer to this question is: it is still running on your computer, but it is not in the same thread as your execution stack.

First, I want to talk about v8 engine. V8 is one of the javascript engines and javascript engine is mostly provided by browser vendors. The very first javascript engine was created by the same person who invented javascript. Also, In the video, he mentioned `setTimeout` is not implemented in v8, V8  is just what chrome is using to understand javascript. Therefore, I will say Javascript is just a bunch of letters, but only with javascript engines, such as V8: it understands how javascript thinks.   [Side Note: `node.js` is implemented based on V8 engine, and I will explain your question based on `node.js`.]

Second, the word `api` should be clarified. I don't like to talk about definitions, so I will state my own understanding: `api` is just an interface to make things easier for programmers. It hides difficult works from the user[developers who are using the api]. When we talk about `web-api`, it can be any client-side api, such as [youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference), of course, for the server side, there is restful api too. If you go to check out the `node.js` github, you will see `setTimeout` is implemented in [lib/times.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/timers.js) with language of javascript. In conclusion, the `web-api` he was talking in the video, is just an interface created with javascript.

Third, the statement `javascript is single-threaded` is not 100% true. Javascript runs multiple threads in the background. Of course, if you look at the diagram of event loop, and think about how the queues and event loop works, you may notice that it is impossible with one single thread. Only with multiple threads, javascript is able to run things asynchronously.

Conclusion: V8 did not implement `setTimeout`, `DOM`, so I guess engine natively does not understand `setTimeout`. While, `setTimeout`, `DOM` etc are implemented beyond javascript.
Then, when you were calling `setTimeout` in javascript, it is not compiled directly by engine, but calls another function which is written in javascript. And the body of that function can be compiled by engine in another thread.

Q1:

> where does that web api call go to be executed?

A1:

> Web-api is just being called like a Javascript function, or youtube api, etc

Q2:

> where is it sitting for 5 seconds?

A2:

> Your computer, but a different thread.

Comment: javascript is definitely a single threaded, dealling with async operation waits in anther thread in the browser outside of js as it's time arrive pushed to the stack of js

Answer (score 0):

When someone clicks the link, the "changeColor" event is added to the message queue.

If the message queue is empty, it will be executed on the next tick.  If there are other events already in the queue, then those will be executed first prior to "changeColor" being executed.

Comment: Yes, that's apparent from looking at the image that I linked. Please see my response to Bergi's comment for clarificaiton.

Comment: Bergi above is correct.  The callback function within setTimeout would be added to the event queue after 5 seconds in your scenario above.